# How do I auto run a program when I log into a specific console?

Tags: server, login, console

I would like to automatically run a program when I log on to a specific console (tty1) and no other.

I am running Ubuntu server 10.10 (no x) and I added the following line to my `/etc/init/tty1.conf` to automatically log me in to the first console and it works.

```
exec /bin/login -f USERNAME < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

I have a program (called HomeAuto) that monitors a special data acquisition board and I want it to start when this console logs in.

Is it a matter of simply adding another line to that file too?

Answer (score 3):

Put this in ~/.bashrc

```
[[ $(tty) == '/dev/tty1' ]] && /full/path/to/HomeAuto
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Now to add a complication, This program needs root privileges, ie. sudo /path/HomeAuto. What is the best way to automatically handle that? Can I use input file redirection to enter the password? Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Use sudo /full/path/to/HomeAuto and configure sudo to allow you to run the script without a password. The other option would be to call the script from `/etc/rc.local`